# OpenGL stop color from affecting other geometry

Tags: java, opengl

I have text on a 3D viewport that is colored using glColor, and then I also have geometry stored in a VBO that is rendered before the text is rendered. For some reason, the text color actually affects the VBO color. I don't actually color my VBO right now, so that may be part of the issue. But I try to use glPushAttrib in the text rendering to preserve the color before the text rendering is called, and it isn't working. Code:

```
public static void renderString(Font font, String string, int gridSize, float x, float y, float charWidth, float charHeight, float scale, Color4f color) {
    glPushAttrib(GL_TEXTURE_BIT | GL_ENABLE_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    font.bind();

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);

    glColor4f(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);

    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(scale, scale, 0f);
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
        int code = (int) string.charAt(i);
        float cellSize = 1.0f / gridSize;
        float cellX = ((int) code % gridSize) * cellSize;
        float cellY = ((int) code / gridSize) * cellSize;
        glTexCoord2f(cellX, cellY + cellSize);
        glVertex2f(i * charWidth / 3, y);

        glTexCoord2f(cellX + cellSize, cellY + cellSize);
        glVertex2f(i * charWidth / 3 + charWidth / 2, y);

        glTexCoord2f(cellX + cellSize, cellY);
        glVertex2f(i * charWidth / 3 + charWidth / 2, y + charHeight);

        glTexCoord2f(cellX, cellY);
        glVertex2f(i * charWidth / 3, y + charHeight);
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glPopAttrib();
}
```

And it's called like this:

```
public void render() {
    render3D();

    camera.applyTranslations();
    world.render();
    glLoadIdentity();

    if (renderText) {
        render2D();
        renderText();
    }
}
```

World.render holds my VBO, and as you can see, it's called after the text is called. So how is this possible? How can I reset the color so it doesn't affect other geometry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're wondering why your use of `glPushAttrib` / `glPopAttrib` doesn't have the desired effect of returning the OpenGL state machine into the state before you made the changes.

Let's just note for the moment that the attrib stack has been deprecated and is no longer supported in modern OpenGL, but you're not using the modern feature set anyway.

A quick glance at the [documentation of `glPushAttrib`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushAttrib.xml) reveals that `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` will not make OpenGL store the color attribute state. That is done by the `GL_CURRENT_BIT` flag, which affects the whole vertex attribute state.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is a state machine--there is no sense of "object-specific" color.  Once you set the color, it stays that way until you explicitly change it.  In general, if you want something to be drawn in a certain color, you must set that color before (or during) the drawing calls for that object.

Comment: If you would read the question, you would realize I know that, and that's why I want to use glPushAttrib. But you know! Stackoverflow is just about not reading apparently.

Comment: @opiop65:  I did read the question, and I stand by my advice.  The attribute stack is both deprecated and way too heavy handed to achieve what you're attempting to do here.  Just set the color for each object just before you render it & you don't have to muck about with pushing/popping loads of GL state.